# How to rename an image retrieved from phone gallery and save it with new name

Tags: android, gallery, filepath

I am getting image from gallery through this code:

accepted
The other answers explained how to send the intent, but they didn't explain well how to handle the response. Here's some sample code on how to do that:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, 
       Intent imageReturnedIntent) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, imageReturnedIntent); 

    switch(requestCode) { 
    case REQ_CODE_PICK_IMAGE:
        if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){  
            Uri selectedImage = imageReturnedIntent.getData();
            String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};

            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(
                               selectedImage, filePathColumn, null, null, null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();

            int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
            String filePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
            cursor.close();


            Bitmap yourSelectedImage = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath);
        }
    }
}
```

Now, I want to get the file name from filepath, rename it and save it again. Is this possible? If yes, how?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Its always possible!

```
//get file
File photo = new File(filePath);

//file name
String fileName = photo.getName();

//resave file with new name
File newFile = new File("new file name");
photo.renameTo(newFile);
```

Comment: The renameTo() method just returns false for me everytime. I'm using Samsung device to debug (With Read and Write permissions on external storage)